# React how to reset GIF upon project refresh?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animated-gif

Given :

```js
function App() {

    return (
            <div className="container"> 
              <span>
           
              </span>
            </div>
       );
   }

   
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.container {
background-color: black;
width: 100vw;
height:100px;
display: flex;
position: relative;
}

.container::before {
background: url('https://s9.gifyu.com/images/chain.gif');
background-size:cover;
content: '';
width: 100px;
height:100px;
right:35px;
bottom:-10px;
position:absolute;
z-index: 999 !important;
}

.container::after {
 background: url('https://s9.gifyu.com/images/chain.gif');
background-size:cover;
content: '';
width: 100px;
height:100px;
right:80px;
bottom:-15px;
position:absolute;
rotate: -10deg;
z-index: 999 !important;
}

.container > span:before {
content: '';
background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
width: 75px;
height:40px;

right:80px;
bottom:-55px;
rotate: -7deg;

border: 3px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
position:absolute;
z-index: 999 !important;

/* transform: rotate(1deg) translate(279px, 28px);
animation: T-animation 3s linear infinite alternate-reverse; */
animation: animationFrames linear 6.25s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
-webkit-animation: animationFrames linear 6.25s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/  
}

  
@keyframes animationFrames{
0% {
  transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
20% {
  transform:  translate(-14px,-8px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
29% {
  transform:  translate(-14px,-8px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
51% {
  transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
72% {
  transform:  translate(65px,-1px)  rotate(7deg) ;
}
79% {
  transform:  translate(65px,-1px)  rotate(7deg) ;
}
100% {
  transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
 }
}
  
@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
0% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
20% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(-14px,-8px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
29% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(-14px,-8px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
51% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
}
72% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(65px,-1px)  rotate(7deg) ;
}
79% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(65px,-1px)  rotate(7deg) ;
}
100% {
  -webkit-transform:  translate(35px,-2px)  rotate(-3deg) ;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="app"></div>
```

with [JSFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcx0adym/30/),

I want to find a way to run the background gifs and the animations at the same time upon refresh or something similar. Currently, if you click `run code snippet` they are probably synchronized, but if the page is refreshed the gifs keep playing in the background whilst the animation is reloaded.

For instance if the `run code snippet` is clicked multiple times, the gif just keeps playing continuously while the animation restarts.

It is tedious for me to design this animation if every time I restart my program the gif and the animation are unsynchronized.

---

#### Things I have tried

I have tried changing `<div className="container" />`  to `<div />`, refresh, then change back, but that doesn't seem to fix it. I have also tried to change my `App.js` to

```
 const [loaded,setState] = React.useState("container");

const reloadGif = () => {
    React.setState({loaded: ''})
    setTimeout(() => {
      React.setState({loaded: "container"})
    }, 0)
  }

return (
   <div className={loaded}> 
   <button onClick={reloadGif}>Reset</button>
     <span>
       
     </span>
   </div>
);
```

}

ReactDOM.render(, document.querySelector("#app"));

but clicking on the `replay` button doesn't reset the gif and animation at all.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem ?